# Create a Field that only accepts SharePoint groups

Tags: 2013, column, groups, spsite

I need to create a SharePoint 2013 field that only accepts groups (from SP, not AD). I know I can add `UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"` to make it accept only people, but I want the opposite. Is there any way I can accomplish this? Thanks!

EDIT1: Just to clarify, I do not want to pick users from a specific group, but select "SPGroup"s from a people picker control

EDIT2: Thanks for all the help! For now, I'm gonna go with an event receiver to validate the value against the groups of the site. Maybe I'll change to the `PrincipalAccountType` solution later.

Comment: did you try `PrincipalAccountType="SPGroup"`?

Comment: That's what I'm looking at right now.

Comment: So have a look on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying `PrincipalAccountType="SPGroup"` as [*MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker_members.aspx) says.

> String used to specify the type of principals to be resolved in a
>   query Comma-separated : "User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup"

Answer (score 0):

Create field and while creating come at down near Choose from option and select Share Point Groups and define group name under Choose from:.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UserSelectionScope="GroupID"` attribute to specify a group in your **CAML query**. `GroupID` is a group ID (integer).

You can see property description on the MSDN [field schema description page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575(v=office.15).aspx)